# Karate 'could not find or read file' on Jenkins buid

Tags: karate

I have a feature file with:

```
Given path 'mypath'
And def text = karate.readAsString('classpath:files/myfile.csv')
```

which works on my local PC, but when I run on a Jenkins build server:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: my.feature:16 - could not find or read file: classpath:files/myfile.csv at ?.And def text = karate.readAsString('classpath:files/myfile.csv') (my.feature:16)
```

The file is in test/resources

Using Karate 0.9.5

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. Had to remove this from pom build:

```
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

I have my resources and java files all under src/test/java